# In Swift, how do I decode both lower case and pascal case JSON using Decodable protocol?

Tags: ios, json, swift, codable

Until recently, I have been able to decode both lower case ("fooBar") JSON and pascal case ("FooBar") JSON using the Decodable protocol by simply including a CodingKeys enum like this...

```
enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
    case bars = "Bars"
}
```

That has allowed me to decode JSON in either of these forms: `{"bars":[]}` or `{"Bars":[]}`

But that no longer works for me.

The complete example is below. When I run this code, only the JSON that has the Pascal case fieldnames are decoded. The only way to decode the lower case JSON is to either change the CodingKeys to lower case (which simply matches the defined fieldnames) or remove them completely.

Example:

```
import UIKit

struct Foo: Codable {
    var bars: [Bar]
    
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case bars = "Bars"
    }

    struct Bar: Codable {
        var barBaz: String
        
        enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
            case barBaz = "BarBaz"
        }
    }
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        let fooBars = [
            "{\"bars\": [{\"barBaz\": \"abc\"}]}",
            "{\"Bars\": [{\"BarBaz\": \"abc\"}]}",
            "{\"Bars\": [{\"BarBaz\": \"abc\"},{\"BarBaz\": \"def\"}]}",
            "{\"Bars\": []}",
            "{\"bars\": []}"
        ]
        
        fooBars.forEach {
            if let fooBar = $0.data(using: .utf8) {
                do {
                    let data = try JSONDecoder().decode(Foo.self, from: fooBar)
                    print("Success:\nFound \(data.bars.count) bar(s).\n")
                } catch {
                    print("Fail:\n\(error)\n")
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
}
```

Output:

```
Fail:
keyNotFound(CodingKeys(stringValue: "Bars", intValue: nil), Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [], debugDescription: "No value associated with key CodingKeys(stringValue: \"Bars\", intValue: nil) (\"Bars\").", underlyingError: nil))

Success:
Found 1 bar(s).

Success:
Found 2 bar(s).

Success:
Found 0 bar(s).

Fail:
keyNotFound(CodingKeys(stringValue: "Bars", intValue: nil), Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [], debugDescription: "No value associated with key CodingKeys(stringValue: \"Bars\", intValue: nil) (\"Bars\").", underlyingError: nil))
```

My apps that still reference old Codable classes with this CodingKey approach do still work. So, I suspect I must be doing something wrong in this particular example.

Can anybody please explain what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Expecting that to work was always wrong. I'm very surprised it ever worked; it violates the JSON format. But to get that behavior intentionally, see https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/jsondecoder/keydecodingstrategy/custom. You can create a custom strategy that normalizes all strings to what you want.

Comment: Yes, it sounds like they fixed a bug.

Comment: "violates the JSON format" is actually too strongly said. The JSON format spec says nothing about case-sensitivity. It doesn't say anything about ordering or key uniqueness, either. Almost everything is left up to the parser to decide. So ignore when I said that. But I'm still quite surprised it ever worked.

Comment: Given that it is *Javascript object notation* and JavaScript keys are case sensitive, it would certainly be strongly implied that json keys should be case sensitive.

Comment: You might be correct @Paulw11. I was going to mention that I previously installed the latest version of XCode.

Comment: Thanks @RobNapier. I did find that the only solution that allowed me to interpret both lower case and pascal case was just like you said - creating my own custom decoder.

Comment: I do have full control over the allowed format. Would it be preferable to simply only allow camelCase for all of my JSON?

Comment: Yes, since you get decoding that for free by Codable. And more importantly it would be preferable to be consistent.

Comment: Makes sense. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @JoelS. you should post your solution as an answer rather than editing it into your question. You can then (after a day) accept your own answer. Questions with accepted answers tend to rank higher in search, which will make this more useful to others.

Comment: Done @Nick. Thanks. I'm still learning my way around SO.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to accomplish this by implementing a custom initializer like this...

```
enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
    case bars, Bars
}

init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
    let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
            
    if let bars = try? container.decode([Bar].self, forKey: .bars) {
        self.bars = bars
    } else if let bars = try? container.decode([Bar].self, forKey: .Bars) {
        self.bars = bars
    }
}
```

This allows me to capture the values as they are being decoded and parse them to their appropriate properties. Now I can read `{"bars":[]}` and `"{Bars:[]}"` into the `bars` property.

Comment: This will fail silently in case it doesn't decode your json. Don't ignore the errors using `try?`. You should always catch the errors. Btw `data(using: .utf8)` will never fail.

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on Joel own answer. Your code will fail silently in case it doesn't decode your json. Don't ignore the errors using try?. You should always catch them. Btw `data(using: .utf8)` will never fail. You can safely force unwrap the result or use Data non falible initializer `Data($0.utf8)`

A proper implementation of your custom decoder should be something like this:

```
struct Foo: Decodable {
    let bars: [Bar]
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case bars, Bars
    }
    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        do {
            bars = try container.decode([Bar].self, forKey: .bars)
        } catch {
            bars = try container.decode([Bar].self, forKey: .Bars)
        }
    }
    struct Bar: Decodable {
        let barBaz: String
        enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
            case barBaz, BarBaz
        }
        init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
            let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
            do {
                barBaz = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .barBaz)
            } catch {
                barBaz = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .BarBaz)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Good points. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This is a different approach with a custom key decoding strategy, it makes the first character of all CodingKeys lowercase

```
extension JSONDecoder.KeyDecodingStrategy {
    static var lowerCamelCase: JSONDecoder.KeyDecodingStrategy {
        .custom {
            let currentKey = $0.last!.stringValue
            return AnyKey(stringValue: currentKey.first!.lowercased() + currentKey.dropFirst())! }
    }
}
```

It requires a custom CodingKey

```
public struct AnyKey: CodingKey {
   public let stringValue: String
   public init?(stringValue: String) { self.stringValue = stringValue }
   public var intValue: Int? { return nil }
   public init?(intValue: Int) { return nil }
}
```

Now apply the strategy, it gets rid of the `CodingKeys` enum

```
struct Foo: Codable {
    let bars: [Bar]

    struct Bar: Codable {
        let barBaz: String
    }
}

let fooBars = [
    "{\"bars\": [{\"barBaz\": \"abc\"}]}",
    "{\"Bars\": [{\"BarBaz\": \"abc\"}]}",
    "{\"Bars\": [{\"BarBaz\": \"abc\"},{\"BarBaz\": \"def\"}]}",
    "{\"Bars\": []}",
    "{\"bars\": []}"
]

let decoder = JSONDecoder()
decoder.keyDecodingStrategy = .lowerCamelCase
fooBars.forEach {
    let data = Data($0.utf8)
    do {
        let fooBar = try decoder.decode(Foo.self, from: data)
        print("Success:\nFound \(fooBar.bars.count) bar(s).\n")
    } catch {
        print("Fail:\n\(error)\n")
    }
}
```

Comment: That seems clever. I'll check it out. Thanks @vadian!